# TypeError: Cannot read property ''$id' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

The error message is pointing to line 13236 of the angular.js source file. It's strange, I rolled it back on the server to a point where I *know* I wasn't getting this error yet the error still shows up. Which makes me think it has nothing to do with my code and if it does, I have no idea what it could be so I don't know what to include here as code. Here is the github: https://github.com/muninn9/powerpot and url: https://eskil-todo-api.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I see no problems... how do you trigger it? Why don't you make it a snippet here and reproduce the issue?

Comment: I really don't know how it got triggered it just all of a sudden appeared. I tried back tracking and commenting out all the new code I put in and, like I said, I even rolled it back on the server quite a ways but it's still there!

Comment: Interesting, now that I view it in a different browser I don't see it either. It seems to be Chrome that is the issue.

Comment: In what browser did you see it?

Comment: I use Chrome, I don't see any problem.

Comment: Yeah I don't know, I cleared my cache and it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue had to do with using jquery with Angular. I was using jquery for Bootstrap. "The way jQuery works to manipulate data in your views fights directly with how you use Angular to manipulate your views. When building out Angular projects, you should not add on the full jQuery library. jQlite is already included in Angular and this should be all the jQuery that is necessary." https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together

The problem is now resolved after removing Bootstrap and jquery references and using Angular-UI Bootstrap.